# Determine if Chrome has blocked HTML5 video autoplay?

Tags: javascript, html, google-chrome, html5-video

As of Chrome 46, new background tabs will no longer autoplay audio or video. How can an application tell if its autoplay has been blocked?

Some ideas:

- UA sniff for Chrome 46+
- check if tab is visible with Visibility API
- check if new tab with History API
- check if video is actually playing

Something hacky like this will probably work, but I would really like to know if there's a better way:

```
function isAutoplayBlocked() {
  return isChrome46 && isNewTab && isHiddenTab;
}
```

Comment: it being "new tab" is not a requirement for video autoplaying to be blocked.  For example, go to youtube, click on a video and before page is loaded go to another tab. The video will not play.

Comment: According to the commit: "Once a tab / RenderFrame has ever played media before, it's allowed to continue to autoplay/autoload indefinitely". So your scenario is only true when the tab hasn't already played media. But you're right that I had a wrong assumption.

Answer (score 0):

Firstly on mobile, autoplay is completely blocked.

The best way to see if your video is blocked is to look for the media events that indicate that the element has started playing such as `ontimeupdate` and your element has autoplay attribute attached.  If there are no updates and no user interactions then you can assume that autoplay has been suspended.